# Find Length of All links in a Binary Tree Network in R

Tags: r, binary-tree

I have a table that defines a binary tree with thousands of individual links. The table has arbitrarily defined, numeric link names, arbitrarily defined parent links (PL) (where -1 indicates no parent) and there is never 1 parent, and the length of each link. I would like to construct a table that has each link and its total distance from the base of link 1.

Example:
[image: Network with 9 Links]

For the above network I would have this data.frame though in practice there is no pattern to the naming of the links:

```
test_data <- data.frame(Link = seq(1, 9, 1),
                    PL1 = c(2, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1),
                    PL2 = c(3, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1),
                    Len = c(15, 17, 81, 9, 42, 7, 13, 64, 36))
```

And I would like to have a table like this:

```
result <- data.frame(Link = seq(1, 9, 1),
                     Len = c(15, 15+17, 15+81, 15+17+9, 15+17+42, 15+81+7, 15+81+13, 15+81+13+64, 15+81+13+36))
```

where, for example, the length of Link7 (L7) = L1 + L3 + L7. The above code shows this work but I would like the table to contain the total sum. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using the `igraph` package.  It has a plethora of functions so there might be a more direct way but this gets you to your desired result:

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

plot_dat <- test_data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Link, Len)) %>%
  select(Link, value) %>%
  filter(value != -1) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame()

plot_dat %>%
  plot(layout = layout_as_tree(.))
```

[image]

```
n <- neighborhood(plot_dat, mode = "in")

all_simple_paths(plot_dat, from = as_ids(n[lengths(n) == 1][[1]])) %>%
  map(~ as.numeric(as_ids(.x))) %>%
  enframe(value = "path") %>%
  mutate(Link = map_dbl(path, last)) %>%
  left_join(test_data, ., by = "Link") %>%
  mutate(Len_total = replace(map_dbl(path, ~ sum(Len[match(.x, Link)])), 1, Len[1])) %>%
  select(Link, Len = Len_total)

  Link Len
1    1  15
2    2  32
3    3  96
4    4  41
5    5  74
6    6 103
7    7 109
8    8 173
9    9 145
```

Comment: Thank You. Unfortunately this did not work for my actual data. It may be important to reiterate that the link names are random numerical values (i.e., no numerical sequence between parent and child links and ranging between 300 and 300,000 for 2500ish links). The only way that I can think to set up the network in R is to incorporate the PL1 and PL2 columns some how. Any additional thoughts or insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you make your example data more representative of your actual data?  Arbitrary values shouldn't be an issue but I need to see *how* it doesn't work to make further suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for the vague comment. I tried the code again with random numbers instead of the 1 thru 9 sequence I provided above and it worked great. I also tried shuffling the order around to see if that mattered in constructing the network (it appears not to). Unfortunately when I try it with my full data all but only a few Len values are 0 which is not correct.

Comment: Have edited.  Please re-try the code.  Again, this assumes a single tree structure.

Comment: I got it working... I had to change the "from" in "all_simple_paths(plot_dat, 1)". Thanks Again.